# What really is a "Yester" in Yesterday or Yesteryear?

Tags: meaning, etymology, cranberry-morphemes

Apparently, **Yester** cannot be used alone in a sentence, except when accompanied by "day *(yesterday)* or year *(yesteryear)*". It cannot be used incombination with other portions of *time* like; yestermonth, yesterweek, yestersecond, yesterminute, yesterhour or yestermillisecond. So what is "Yester"?

Comment: http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=yesterday&searchmode=none

Comment: According to *dictionary.com*, the term [*yesterweek*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/yester) existed.

Comment: Plenty, nay eons of [yesterweeks](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=yesterweek&tbm=bks) in Google books.

Comment: Six instances for [*yestermonth*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=yestermonth&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899&tbm=bks) in the 19th century

Comment: Not to mention [yesternight](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=yesternight).

Comment: I may start using *yesterhour* and *yesterminute*

Comment: A Google Books search turns up more than fifty matches for _yestertime_, which appears to mean simply "the past." The matches date back to [1884](https://books.google.com/books?id=3CwHAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA68&dq=%22yestertime%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jonfVLCWJYzvoASrlICwAw&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22yestertime%22&f=false). It also yields seven matches for _yesterplace_, four for _yestergone_, two for _yesterways_ (clearly not typos), and one for _yesterculture_ (which sounds as though it ought to refer to a thriving colony of yeast).

Answer (score 11):

"yesterday" is related to German gestern (the last day/ day before today) and Latin heri. From heri an adjective form was derived: hesternus. Change h in hestern.. to g and you get gestern or change h in hester... to y and you get yester. (This play with letters is a simplification. English y surely did not develop from Latin h.)

The etymology of heri is not clear. There are a lot of old  Indo-European variants, but they are mere variants and there is no idea of what might be behind heri.
My idea would be that Latin heri might be related with the Latin verb form fuere, then the idea behind heri would simply be: the day that was.

So the question "What is a yester? may be asked, of course, but as you see some words have a development of two thousand years and more and not every word element was a noun.

Comment: It seems like English has only allowed yester to be in front of "day" and "year", if you just type "yestermonth or week" even in a MS Word document, you'll immediately see it marked as Error... Why Only "Day" and "Year" and nothing else?

Comment: The distribution of initial Latin _h-_, German _g-_, and English _y-_ before a front vowel is perfectly regular. They are all the regular, straightforward development of PIE _*ĝʰ(e/i)-_. @Erick Never trust MS Word’s spellchecker (or any other spellchecker) to know what is and is not a word. _Yesterweek_ used to be a perfectly fine word, and _yestermonth_ was used, too. They just happen to have fallen out of use.

Comment: Also, that there is “no idea what might be behind _heri_” is not true at all. There are lots of cognates, all meaning ‘yesterday’ or ‘the other day’, to the PIE _*dʰĝʰi̯es-_, which is quite simply the nominal stem _*dʰeĝʰ-_ ‘day’ (the root found in the English word ‘day’) + a contrastive suffix _*-i̯es-/-i̯os-_, which also functions as one of the ways to create comparatives of adjectives (in Latin, it shows up as _-ior/-ius_; in Germanic, it underlies the regular comparative ending _-er_). So it’s just “that day [as opposed to this one]”. No connection with _fuere_ at all.

Comment: Cognates only show a similiar form. And a construct of common consonants as IE root is simply a consonant skeleton. But such things don't show in any way what was the idea that lead to the Latin word formation heri. A word form and its meaning is one thing, but the idea why people coined this word is something totally different and you don't find it in cognates or in IE roots.

Comment: Actually, the term arose from harried husbands whose wives were constantly telling them "I told you to do that the day before today!"  Hence the day before today came to be known as "yes-dear-day".

Answer (score 6):

Further to rogermue's answer: according to [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=yesteryear), **yesteryear** (n.) was

> coined 1870 by Dante Gabriel Rossetti from yester- + year to translate
>   French antan (from Vulgar Latin *anteannum "the year before") in a
>   refrain by François Villon: Mais ou sont les neiges d'antan? which
>   Rossetti rendered "But where are the snows of yesteryear?"

It was a nonce word, obviously modelled on 'yesterday'. It caught on. Many don't.

What might be called the literal sense (last year) is, however, rarely used:

**yesteryear** (plural yesteryears). (poetic) Past years; time gone by; yore. (rare) Last year. [Wiktionary]

Comment: The French word *antan* means *"last year"*, it doesn't mean *"past years; time gone by"* (except metaphorically in Villon's poem). So I wouldn't call that the original sense.

Answer (score 5):

"Yester" is what's called a "[cranberry morpheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranberry_morpheme)", (like the "cran" of "cranberry") meaning it has no meaning on its own but serves to distinguish words.

Comment: so, where is it appropriate?... why is it conditioned to "day" and "year"? why not yestermonth, yesterweek, yestersecond, yesterminute, yesterhour or yestermillisecond, any idea???

Comment: Because you normally use "last" as in last month, last year, etc.

Comment: I admire the inventiveness of morpheme-theorists. Cranberry-morpheme is a nice term, but I think I will never need it.

Comment: @ErickBest: because _yester_ derives from a word that means _yesterday_. As such, yesterday means yesterdayday. Which means yesterdaydayday. Even _yesteryear_ I would see as a tricky neologism, often used by people who may eventually consider yesterweek and yestermonth. Just give it time :)

Comment: It seems like English has only allowed yester to be in front of "day" and "year", if you just type "yestermonth or week" even in a MS Word document, you'll immediately see it marked as _Error_... Why Only "Day" and "Year" and nothing else?

Comment: @ErickBest: I just told you that. It was only appropriate (and even redundant) in front of _day_, because _yester_ means _yesterday_. The combination with day is normal, because the sense of _day_ already resided in _yester_. In Dutch or German (gisteren, gestern), asking why "gestern" doesn't combine with _woche_ (week) makes as much sense as asking why we don't say _yesterdayweek_ in English. English has slapped a _day_ on _yester_, a bit redundantly, but that doesn't mean the "prefix" now has to combine with every other time period.

Comment: @oerkelens - your answer is, of course, spot on. I think, though, that the OP may have been asking that of nohat. I think his answer is lacking in exactly that element. *"cranberry morpheme"* is nice, but really, it doesn't explain *yeste* like you and rogermue did.

Comment: I think cranberry morpheme is the stuff they gave me when I had my last kidney stone.